# Rendering edit form via ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, simple-form

I am attempting to render a form via ajax. It works fine for creating a new venue, but when attempting to edit an existing venue the venue data should load into the form. The form (_modal) is rendered when the edit venue link is called, however the form is processed as a new form, with all fields blank. Calling @venue at the binding.pry, we see the correct venue object.

How would I get the form to process as edit rather than new? Ideas:

- ```
  respond_to do |format| 
         format.js   { *do stuff* }
  ```
- Add more parameters to form?
- Do it manually - change form attributes and/or fill in data with jquery

Appreciate any suggestions!

_modal.html.erb:

```
<section id="venue-modal" class='modal' title="Venue Form" class="">
  <%= simple_form_for(@venue, remote: true) do |v| %>
    <div id='closeButton'><a href='#'>x</a></div>
  <% binding.pry %>
    <%= v.input :name, label: "Venue Name" %>
    <%= v.input :city %>
    <%= v.input :state, collection: States.us_states %>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= v.submit 'Submit', class: 'button' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</section>
```

Renders following html:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/venues" class="simple_form new_venue" data-remote="true" id="new_venue" method="post">
```

Link calling the modal:

```
<%= link_to edit_venue_path(venue), :remote => true, :class => "edit_venue_link" do %>
```

Controller:

```
def edit
  id = params[:id]
  if id == 'new'
    @venue = Venue.new
  else
    @venue = Venue.find(id)
  end
end
```

Venue.js:

```
$('.edit_venue_link').on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
// stuff happens
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the modal content with this line of code in modal.js.erb:

```
$('#venue-modal').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'venues/modal') %>");
```

Controller:

```
def edit
  id = params[:id]

  if id == 'new'
    @venue = Venue.new
  else
    @venue = Venue.find(id)
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render 'venues/modal' }
  end
end
```

Section tags moved out of the modal partial. The form then recognizes @venue and the fields load appropriately.